# How to execute an Azure Function with Blob Trigger on blobs that already exist?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

How to execute an Azure Function with Blob Trigger on blobs that already exist?

I made a new Azure Function that has a Blob Trigger, in C#, and deployed it up to a production environment in Azure. There are tens of thousands of blobs that I need this function to execute on. All of these blobs have been in storage since before this new Function existed. How can I trigger this Function for each of these existing blobs?

On my local development environments, this Function seemed to automatically trigger for all of the blobs that already existed in my Azurite emulator. Doesn't seem to be doing that on Azure, though.

[I did check the blob receipts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574763/running-blob-storage-trigger-over-existing-files-multiple-times), in storage, and it did seem to create 1 single blob receipt which means it ran on one blob, I guess. But it didn't do any more. I tried deleting that blob receipt to see if it'd run it again and now there are no blob receipts.

Is there a way to tell Azure Functions that it needs to trigger my new Function on all of these existing blobs?

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71428203/how-to-run-blob-storage-trigger-multiple-times-over-existing-files) which has an answer to deal with this exact scenario. Other than that... you'd have to modify an existing blob to cause the trigger to fire.

Comment: I had seen that other question and even linked to a similar one in my question here. I've deleted the blob receipt but nothing is happening. No new receipts and no executions showing up in the logs.